# How to create new typename from the typename pass in a template class

Tags: c++, templates

Suppose I am having a template class

```
template <class DATA>
class Stack { 
  //Some implementation
}
```

Inside this stack class I am calling a utility class which is also template. But datatype its handling is of type UltityDATA. That is if we create the object of class stack using following code

```
 stack<MyData> s
```

Internally it should call **UltityMyData**. I dont want to expose UltityMyData stucture to the clients. I have already written implementation for coverting MyData to UltityMyData . Only My requirement is how to convert DATA typename to UtilityDATA typename when I am calling my library class.

---

I have wrritten following code as per your suggestion

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
#include <stdexcept>

using namespace std;
struct RTI 
{
    int a;
};

struct DDSRTI 
{
    int b;
};

// other specialization you might need in the future
 template<class Data>
 struct DDS
{
    typedef DDSData type;
};
template <class T>
class MyStack { 
  private: 
   T a;
  public: 
      MyStack()
      {
       //  cout<< a;
      }
}; 
#define STACK(T) Stack<DDS##T>
template <class T>
class Stack { 
  private: 
  Stack<T> a;
  STACK(T) b;
  public: 
      Stack()
      {
         ///cout<< a;
      }
};
```

But I am getting error as  **error: 'DDST' was not declared in this scope**
Basically preprocessor only appending two values and creating a new type. As per my understanding template will be convert at the time of compilation. DDS#T its taking as a new data type not as template type.

Comment: Is `UtilityMyData` designed as a template class also? It would be helpful if you shown the declaration.

Comment: No it's not possible, the template class (`Stack` in your case) doesn't know the actual type used for instantiating, so there's no way inside the C++ language that will allow that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have a struct specializing a type definition according to your needs

```
// non specialized type
template<typename T>
struct UtilType {};

// specialization for DATA
template<>
struct UtilType<DATA>
{
    typedef UtilityDATA type;
};

// other specialization you might need in the future
template<>
struct UtilType<NewType>
{
    typedef UtilityNewType type;
};
```

You would then use this helper class as so

```
template<typename T>
class Stack
{
    // .....
    typedef typename UtilType<T>::type dataType; //converts DATA typename to UtilityDATA
    // .....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `traits` pattern:

```
template <class DATA, class TRAITS>
class Stack 
{ 
  //Some implementation
}
```

and instanciate like this:

```
stack<MyData, UtilityMyData> s;
```

However, this will require your users to explicitly name the utility class. If you don't mind using the pre-processor you could use a macro:

```
#define STACK(T) Stack<T, Utility##T>
```

And then you'd write:

```
  STACK(MyData) s;
```

It's not pretty, but it might be acceptable to your users

Comment: Why a macro! Thats horrible. Just use a default template parameter,  as all standard library containers do

Comment: @Manu343726 - yes macros are horrible, but if you read the question you'll see that you can't use a default template parameter

Comment: No, only says that UtilityMyData has not to be exposed to the public. Create a tag type like `default_data`, use it as default parameter, and internaly use it to select UtilityMyData or not (with std::conditional for example)

Comment: Also the point of the parameter defaulted to MyUtility is that **users has not to write MyUtility**. So that solution is perfectly reasonable

Comment: @Manu343726 - maybe post your suggestions as an answer

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can just move it to some internal template structure?

```
template <class DATA>
class Stack {
  public:   
    template <class Data>
      struct UtilData {
        template <class... Args>
          UtilData(Args&&... args) : d{std::forward<From>(args)...} {}
            // other operators
          Data d;
        };

    void push(DATA&& d) {
      s.push(UtilData<DATA>{d});
    }
  std::stack<UtilData<DATA>> s;
};
```

Update: Sorry, I misunderstood your question. For some concrete types MyData and UtilMyData you can use boost::mpl::map:

```
using boost::mpl::pair;
using boost::mpl::map;
using boost::mpl::at;

typedef map<pair<SomeOther, Some>/*, other pairs of types here*/> TypeMap;

at<TypeMap, SomeOther>::type s; // s has type Some
```